# Best way to find anchor tag not containing href attribute?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have a html string.. Some of the anchor tags in it doesnt have href attribute (without href attribute and without any value). I am trying to remove those tags from the HTML string

Example:

```
<div class="parsys ReferenceA"><div class="parbase section reference"><div style="display:inline;" class="cq-dd-paragraph"><div class="warrantyinfo warrantyinfo_3"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/media/test.css" type="text/css"> 
         <div class="box note warranty-info hidebox"> 
                 <p><a name="test" data-cqpath="234492921271682679940756642751399440576;2014296"></a><b>some text</p> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="parbase section reference"><div style="display:inline;" class="cq-dd-paragraph"><div class="warrantyinfo"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/media/test.css" type="text/css"> 
         <div class="box note warranty-info hidebox"> 
                 <p><a name="test" data-cqpath="84618115959711848855398939109764576374;2014212"></a>some text</p> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="parbase section reference"><div style="display:inline;" class="cq-dd-paragraph"><div class="warrantyinfo_0 warrantyinfo"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/media/test.css" type="text/css"> 
         <div class="box note warranty-info hidebox"> 
                 <p><b>Bsome text<br> 
<br> 
<b>some text/p> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="parbase section reference"><div style="display:inline;" class="cq-dd-paragraph"><div class="warrantyinfo"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/media/test.css" type="text/css"> 
         <div class="box note warranty-info hidebox"> 
                 <p>some text<br> 
</p> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<div class="parbase section reference"><div style="display:inline;" class="cq-dd-paragraph"><div class="warrantyinfo"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://test.com/test,css" type="text/css"> 
         <div class="box note warranty-info hidebox"> 
                 <p>some text</p> 
<p></p> 
         </div> 
        </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

I tried the below code but didn't work

data is a html string returned on ajax request.

```
var newHtml = $('<div>' + data + '</div>');
newHtml.find("a:not([href])").replaceWith(function() { return this.childNodes; });
var content = newHtml.html();
```

Any inputs is appreciated..

**Update:**

Added sample html.

For some reason empty tags are not getting replaced at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/8WpDn/51/

If I inspect the output html I can still see the below emppty  tag

```
<p><a name="test" data-cqpath="84618115959711848855398939109764576374;2014212"></a>some text</p>
```

Comment: I can't think of easier way to find `<a>` elements without an `href`, but it looks like you're taking a more-complicated approach than need-be to implementing [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

Comment: Can you give a simple example of what's in your `data` variable? Because that *looks* like it should work, but apparently "didn't," which is a very vague description of the problems you encountered. Could you be a little more thorough?

Comment: The code you posted works. BTW, historically `<a name=x>` was used to navigate to a part of the page. In HTML5 this is done with id. There is no name attribute for A tags in html5 so you may want to replace `<a name=x>` with `<span id=x>`

Comment: OP needs to describe what's `not working`, did it replace the wrong thing or not replacing at all

Answer (score 0):

Your approach [works](http://jsfiddle.net/8WpDn/48/).

As David Thomas has noted, JQuery already implements what you're doing with [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/).

`newHtml.find("a:not([href])").contents().unwrap()`, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8WpDn/49/).

*EDIT*: I am seeing the empty links problem your edit mentions, but only with unwrap()! Your approach [really does work](http://jsfiddle.net/8WpDn/56/)! :)

Comment: it works **only** when there is text in between `<a>`

Answer (score -2):

try [.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
newHtml.find("a:not([href])").remove();
```

Comment: It looks like the sample code supplied was trying to retain child nodes. This solution would remove both the `<a>` and children nodes as well, right?

Comment: from the sample HTML, there isn't a childNode in `<a>`

Comment: You are correct. It shows that the question could use some work.

Comment: I would say the `.remove` still the best approach.